# How to keep a footer with fixed position from overlapping elements on scroll?

Tags: html, css

I've read other SO posts asking this question but it didn't work with the HTML/CSS I have.

https://jsfiddle.net/hmsrj1jh/

```
body, html {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.right {
  background-color: gray;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
}

.left {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width:100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="left">
      </div>

      <div class="right">
        <div id="results">
        </div>
        <div class = "footer">
          Footer
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: giv it a z-index of -1 (or a lower z-index than the items you don't want it to overlap)

Comment: That seemed to completely hide it

Comment: read the bit in brackets